# Minimum number of bytes required

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-efficient

Minimum number of bytes required to store following Object:

1. Integer - Between 0 - 364847
2. Integer - Between 0 - 37337
3. Page Status

   - In use (I'll use single bit)
   - Free
   - Dirty
4. Mode

   - Read Only
   - Write Only
   - Execute Only
   - Read Write
   - Read Execute
   - Read Write Execute

I think minimum 6 bytes will be required but I'm not sure. Also, can we use unused bits inside a byte to store Page Status and Mode?

Comment: How many billions of records are you storing that you need to concern yourself with every precious bit?

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical limit (with arithmetic packing) is `log2(364848*37338*3*6) = 37.8352180528...` bits per record which is less then `5` bytes. But accessing data thus packed will require expensive integer divisions. Think carefully if you really want that.

If you let every field occupy distinct bits, you get `ceil(log2(364848))+ceil(log2(37338))+ceil(log2(3))+ceil(log2(6)) = 40` bits, which is exactly `5` bytes and allows fast access with simple bit shifts and masking.

Comment: Thanks. Can't we use just 3 bits for Mode? 
If it's RW then set Read = 1 and Write =1 and so on. 

`ceil(log2(364848))+ceil(log2(37338))+ceil(log2(3))+ceil(log2(3)) = 39`

Comment: @Kattu `6` is a number of states, not number of bits. That would be `ceil(log2(364848))+ceil(log2(37338))+ceil(log2(3))+3` which is actually the same 40 bits anyway since `ceil(log2‌​(6)) = 3`.